# What does $(number) mean in a Makefile?

Tags: make

I have [some script](https://github.com/crimson-unicorn/core/blob/master/Makefile) and I didn't understand a line which contains `$(1)`:

```
wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=5 --read-timeout=30 --tries=50 --no-dns-cache https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:$(1) -O data/tmp.tar.gz
```

What does `$(1)` represent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$(1)` is the first argument to a GNU make “function”, which is a [variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#index-define) interpreted by the [`call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function) function:

```make
define dataverse_download
    wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=5 --read-timeout=30 --tries=50 --no-dns-cache https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:$(1) -O data/tmp.tar.gz
    cd data && tar -xzf tmp.tar.gz
    rm -f data/tmp.tar.gz
endef

download_wget:
    mkdir -p data
    $(call dataverse_download,10.7910/DVN/IA8UOS/URG8XN)
    $(call dataverse_download,10.7910/DVN/IA8UOS/1DBE7K)
    $(call dataverse_download,10.7910/DVN/IA8UOS/34QRHK)
```

This defines a function, `dataverse_download`, which downloads the datafile matching the DOI given as the first argument; the `download_wget` target shows how to use this with the [`$(call)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function) function.

Comment: @StephenKitt you've been served, feel free to revert. Notice that `$(1)` is the same as `$1` or `${1}`, just like any other one-character macro like `$@` or `a = b ... $a`.